# How to make this progress bar in Android?

Tags: android

> I wand to make this progress bar in android

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO .. Read this before posting questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a customized `drawable` for `progressbar` and use attribute `android:progressDrawable` to set customized `drawable`.

**Try  this:**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:maxHeight="14dip"
    android:minHeight="14dip"
    android:progress="75"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar" />
```

**custom_progressbar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- background color -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#D9D9D9" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- progress color -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#F1C40F" />
                <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use native ProgressBar and set a drawable to its "android:progressDrwable".
the drawable looks like this:

```
<!-- background -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- progress -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<!-- second progress -->
<item android:id="@android:idcondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: miss layer-list